# genfromtxt is not loading 2D asc file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am working on the Jupyter notebook using Python3. I am trying to load an asc file containing 2 columns by using `lin_data1 = np.genfromtxt(outdir+"/test_22/mp_harmonic_im_r8.00.ph.asc")`, I am getting the following error.

```
    'ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-5d1a4cbeab20> in <module>
      1 # format of the path: SIMULATION-NAME/output-NNNN/PARFILE-NAME
      2 
----> 3 lin_data1 = np.genfromtxt(outdir+"/test_22/mp_harmonic_im_r8.00.ph.asc")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in genfromtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, skip_header, skip_footer, converters, missing_values, filling_values, usecols, names, excludelist, deletechars, replace_space, autostrip, case_sensitive, defaultfmt, unpack, usemask, loose, invalid_raise, max_rows, encoding)
   2078             # Raise an exception ?
   2079             if invalid_raise:
-> 2080                 raise ValueError(errmsg)
   2081             # Issue a warning ?
   2082             else:

ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 2 columns instead of 3)
    Line #3 (got 2 columns instead of 3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful to add a bit of sample data to your question (the last part of the traceback indicates that the input isn't as expected).

Comment: Looks the first line(s) split into 3 columns, setting the expectation for all lines. But without a sample of the file we can't help further.